# 2co return paramter suddenly not updating database

Tags: php, mysql, email, 2checkout

I been facing one problem suddenly after few years on one of my client website.

In APRIL 2014 website stop generated order emails after successful payment.
I use 2co for that website.
I found two things

1 MD5 was changed ( MD5 new code implemented ) that error has been fixed
Other I am not sure

I am still not receiving return parameter for order status change, it used to hit back whenever invoice status changed at 2co backened and then a parameter passed on my website and update the database via sql question and generate email.

Order email only generated when payment status is confirmed

Now I am only receiving emails from 2co so as the customer but my website is not generate due to no success parameter coming.

I could generate order email for every single order but mostly payment not verified or fake orders so I don't want junk emails everyday basis.

I also have sql injection code security and when we changed md5 then suddenly parameter was getting caught and url was getting cleaned so the database update and email process was getting stopped.

```
if($_POST["invoice_status"]=="approved"){
$order_id=$_POST["cart_order_id"];`
if($order_id==""){

    $order_id=$_POST["vendor_order_id"];
    }   

$siteUrl=$_SESSION['siteurl'];
$dt=date("Y-m-d");
$userid = getname("orders","id",$order_id,"userid");
$sql="update orders set status='1' , trackOdrStatus='Paid' where id=$order_id";
mysql_query($sql);
 $sql="delete from cart where userid=$userid";
  mysql_query($sql);
 $_SESSION['tamount']=0;

echo "<script>window.location='order_details.php?id=$order_id&email=yes'</script>";
$_SESSION['sb_user']=$userid;
exit;
}
```

===

## 2CO Log

```
[05/31/2014 9:01 PM] - SUCCESS!
IPN POST Vars from gateway:
message_type=INVOICE_STATUS_CHANGED, message_description=Invoice status changed, 

timestamp=2014-05-31 17:01:24, message_id=1697, vendor_id=1385541, vendor_order_id=, 

invoice_id=205290858532, recurring=0, invoice_status=deposited, 

invoice_list_amount=20.99, invoice_usd_amount=20.99, invoice_cust_amount=20.99, auth_exp=2014-06-07, fraud_status=pass, list_currency=USD, cust_currency=USD, 

payment_type=paypal ec, sale_id=205290858298, sale_date_placed=2014-05-31 00:53:10, customer_ip=107.219.202.159, customer_ip_country=United States, customer_first_name=Raj kumar, customer_last_name=Talreja, customer_name=Raj kumar Talreja, 

customer_email=abc@abc.yale.edu, customer_phone=2038434625, ship_status=, ship_tracking_number=, ship_name=, ship_street_address=, ship_street_address2=, ship_city=, ship_state=, ship_postal_code=, ship_country=, bill_street_address=830 Knottingham Dr, bill_street_address2=Apt 2A, bill_city=Schaumburg, bill_state=IL, bill_postal_code=60193, bill_country=USA, item_count=1, item_name_1=Cart purchase:  1331, item_id_1=1331, item_list_amount_1=20.99, item_usd_amount_1=20.99, item_cust_amount_1=20.99, item_type_1=bill, item_duration_1=, item_recurrence_1=, item_rec_list_amount_1=, item_rec_status_1=, item_rec_date_next_1=, item_rec_install_billed_1=, md5_hash=5E0ACF918C2BE323C2DB31F8ADC66924, key_count=56, 
                    IPN Response from gateway Server:
```

Please advise.

Regards
Raj kumar

Comment: if($_POST["invoice_status"]=="approved"){
$order_id=$_POST["cart_order_id"];
if($order_id==""){
$order_id=$_POST["vendor_order_id"];
} 
$siteUrl=$_SESSION['siteurl'];
$dt=date("Y-m-d");
$userid = getname("orders","id",$order_id,"userid");
$sql="update orders set status='1' , trackOdrStatus='Paid' where id=$order_id";
mysql_query($sql);
 $sql="delete from cart where userid=$userid";
  mysql_query($sql);
 $_SESSION['tamount']=0;
echo "<script>window.location='order_details.php?id=$order_id&email=yes'</script>";

Comment: Dont post code in comment.Instead of that edit your question.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question with code.